# Неправильно подключается jQuery через Webpack

Tags: jquery, webpack

В одном из своих модулей импортировал jQuery:

```
import $ from 'jquery'
```

И затем экспортировал его через Webpack:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery'
})
```

При этом в браузере он как-то странно работает. Например, сайт, на котором jQuery импортирован на страницу посредством тэга `<script>`, функции выполняются так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При подключении методом, описанным выше, всё работает вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это исправить?

Comment: потому что ваш метод не работает, в хроме - `The devtools console provides $ as an alias to document.querySelector`

Answer (score 0):

Экспортировать модули в глобальную область видимости получилось только так:

```
window['jQuery'] = $; window['$'] = $;
```

Метод Webpack не срабатывает...